# Example where TYPE_ALIGNMENT() fails

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, alignment

I have a question relating to alignment in C/C++. In 
[Determining the alignment of C/C++ structures in relation to its members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364483/determining-the-alignment-of-c-c-structures-in-relation-to-its-members) Michael Burr posted this macro:

```
#define TYPE_ALIGNMENT( t ) offsetof( struct { char x; t test; }, test )
```

In the comments someone wrote this might fail with non POD types. Can someone give me an code example where this fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offsetof` is only specified to work for POD types.  If a class contains any data members that are not POD, the class itself is not POD.  So, if `t` in your example is a non-POD type, it is not guaranteed to work.

From the C++ standard (18.1/5):

> The macro `offsetof` accepts a restricted set of `type` arguments in this International Standard. `type` shall be a POD structure or a POD union.

So, if you use `offsetof` on a non-POD type, the results are undefined.

Comment: well yes but thats not what I asked. For example 

class foo{
    int i;
    virtual void bar(){
    }
};
int main(){
    std::cout << TYPE_ALIGNMENT(foo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

works fine (8 on Linux x86-64 with GCC 4.4.3) and as I understand undefined there are at least some cases where it does not work. Or is my understanding of undefined wrong?

Comment: @JustMaximumPower:  "Works fine" (or, at least appearing to work fine) is a reasonable outcome for something that is undefined.  "Crashes horribly" is another reasonable outcome.  _Anything_ can happen.  Whether it appears to work or it causes pernicious bugs in your software is entirely implementation-dependent.  It would be unwise to assume that it works for non-POD types.